# How to update an already deployed app?

Tags: .net, azure, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

The starting situation:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- Windows 10 Core installed
- C.Net code deployed as an UWP app, from visual studio as the ARM target.
- Connected to internet and communicating to a (our) remote browser/interface through Microsoft Azure

The problem:

- A desire to remotely update the app on dozens/hundreds of Raspberry Pi systems with the app in question pre-installed.
- There is no store, only azure.
- User input is not desired.

Possible solutions found include:

- articles on side loading - however, it's not a developer enabled phone.
- Pushing "DLC" through azure - however that wouldn't update the main app.
- Loading a secondary app with permissions to shut down, download and restart the "main" app. - This one seems to be the most plausible to me.
- Update through visual studio by connecting to "remote machine". This would be labour intensive, though it might be scriptable. Plus the RPI's will likely be behind a firewall.

Has anyone had experience with developing a similar solution for the above problem?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/store)?

Comment: https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/ - is where one ends up then. Looks like we'll need to sign up for that to start. I'm guessing the store "is" a thing, and azure or not should not matter then?

Comment: Yes, currently, there are some limitations for installing and Servicing apps on Windows 10 IoT Core, you may need OEM special permissions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have already locked yourself in when you said 'deployed as an UWP app' The moment you go with a UWP app, you have no choice but to follow the UWP available options which is side loading or through the store.

If you really really want to remotely update apps, then the only option would be where the app is 'served' as a service from the 'server'. That leaves you with creating a dummy UWP app that then reads all the app stuff from a web server, like a website/webapp. This way, when you want to give your users a new experience, you update your app on the server, and they get the new experience.